# Dagger - Triggering two implementations with one interface

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

Is there a way to bind two implementations to a single interface and trigger the methods of both implementaions simultaneously with interface method call. I want to use two apps for analytics and it would be ideal to trigger them both with one interface

Comment: You can use dagger's multibinding to inject a list of implementation of  a single interface to instances https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/multibindings.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution is to use a delegate implementation.
For an interface and two implementation like this

```java
public interface MyInterface{
  public void myMethode();
}

public class MyInterfaceImplA{
  public void myMethode(){
   return ;
  }
}
public class MyInterfaceImplB{
  public void myMethode(){
   return ;
  }
}
```

You can do a third implementation

```java
  public class MyInterfaceDelegate{
  private List<MyInterface> myInterfaceList;

  public MyInterfaceDelegate(List<MyInterface> myInterfaceList){
  this.myInterfaceList = myInterfaceList;
}

  public void myMethode(){
   myInterfaceList.forEach(MyInterface::myMethode)
  }
}
```

And inject it like that (Or with @Inject) :

```java
@Provided
MyInterfaceImplA implA(){
  return new MyInterfaceImplA(); 
}

@Provided
MyInterfaceImplB implB(){
  return new MyInterfaceImplB(); 
}

@Provided
MyInterface interface(MyInterfaceImplA myInterfaceImplA,MyInterfaceImplB myInterfaceImplB){
  return new MyInterfaceDelegate(Lists.newArrayList(myInterfaceImplA, myInterfaceImplB)); 
}
```